# jQuery .get XML works in IE but not Chrome, Firefox

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax, get

Please can someone advise me why the following code appears to work fine in Internet Explorer, but not in Chrome or Firefox; I've tried all variations I can think of using .get, .ajax, .load but none seem to want to work.  The XML file is one of w3c's examples, and I'm using jquery-latest.min.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $.get("http://www.w3schools.com/xml/simple.xml", function(data){
  $(data).find("food").each(function(){
   alert($(this).find("name").text());
  });
 });
});
```

Thank you for looking over my question!

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's about [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy): IE allows ajax queries on a different host website but other browsers don't.
To by-pass this you can use [JSONP](http://www.zackgrossbart.com/hackito/jsonp-sop/) or perform the query on a local php file which will read the distant site with `file_get_contents` if you have `allow_url_fopen` true.

Comment: And only *some* versions of IE.

Comment: I had this issue once so it was at least one IE ^^

Answer (score -2):

Your 2nd parameter should be your data, not your callback function ([documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/))...

```
jQuery.get( url, [ data ], [ callback(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) ], [ dataType ] )
```

Comment: As most of the parameters are optional, the data parameter is not required. The method will determine what the parameters are from their type.